# percentage calculation of each numbers in different groups in a list in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame and it includes several meals (each meal has different numbers) and each meal has nearly 49 different values from 0 to 3. I need to calculate the percentage of each numbers (0,1,2 and 3) for every meal. So I split my data according to the meal numbers (the code is below)

```
 df1 <- split(df, f=df$Meal_Number)
```

and my output is like that

```
 ***$`52`***
       Meal_Number Meal_Type Class
 **44**         52    Dinner     2
 44.1           52    Dinner     2
 44.2           52    Dinner     1
 44.3           52    Dinner     1
 44.4           52    Dinner     1
 44.5           52    Dinner     1
 44.6           52    Dinner     3
 44.7           52    Dinner     3
 44.8           52    Dinner     3
 44.9           52    Dinner     3
 44.10          52    Dinner     3
```

The problem is that I need to write a for loop but I couldn't do that. I need the number of groups but I don't which function I should use. Also this data just for 1 patient and I have 102 patients. So I need to know the number of groups for using in the for loop. How can I write a for loop for that? I'm really struggled with this.

```
 for (i in 1:n)
 H <- sum(df1[i]$Class==1)/length(df1[i]) ......like that ???
```

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Please share a few rows of sample input before you split. Like 5 rows each from 2 different meal numbers. The nicest way to share sample data is with `dput()` as it will be copy/pasteable and include all data structure information, for example `dput(df[c(1:5, 51:55), ])` for rows 1:5 and 51:55.

Comment: But basically you can do something like `library(dplyr); df |> count(Patient, Meal_Number, Class) |> mutate(percent = n / sum(n), .by = c(Patient, Meal_Number))`, no splitting, no for loops needed.

Comment: OMG!!! It worked and I got everything just in a few seconds... Many and many thanks... You are a real lifesaver...

Answer (score 0):

Here  a `tidyverse` way.

```r
txt <- "Meal_Number Meal_Type Class
 44         52    Dinner     2
 44.1           52    Dinner     2
 44.2           52    Dinner     1
 44.3           52    Dinner     1
 44.4           52    Dinner     1
 44.5           52    Dinner     1
 44.6           52    Dinner     3
 44.7           52    Dinner     3
 44.8           52    Dinner     3
 44.9           52    Dinner     3
 44.10          52    Dinner     3
"
txt <- read.table(text = txt, header = TRUE)
patients <- list(`52` = txt)

suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(purrr)
})

patients %>%
  map(\(x) {
    x %>% 
      count(Meal_Number, Meal_Type, Class, name = "Count") %>%
      mutate(Prop = prop.table(Count))
  })
#> $`52`
#>   Meal_Number Meal_Type Class Count      Prop
#> 1          52    Dinner     1     4 0.3636364
#> 2          52    Dinner     2     2 0.1818182
#> 3          52    Dinner     3     5 0.4545455
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

one way would be to use baseR's `prop.table` function.

##### Calculate percentages per meal-type overall :

```
> prop.table(table(df$Meal_Type,df$Class))
        
                  1          2          3
  Dinner 0.18181818 0.09090909 0.22727273
  Lunch  0.18181818 0.09090909 0.22727273
```

###### Or use `by` to regard Meal number also:

```
> by(df, df[,1:2], \(x){prop.table(table(x$Class))})
Meal_Number: 52
Meal_Type: Dinner

        1         2         3 
0.3636364 0.1818182 0.4545455 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Meal_Number: 53
Meal_Type: Dinner

        1         2         3 
0.3636364 0.1818182 0.4545455 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Meal_Number: 52
Meal_Type: Lunch

        1         2         3 
0.3636364 0.1818182 0.4545455 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Meal_Number: 53
Meal_Type: Lunch

        1         2         3 
0.3636364 0.1818182 0.4545455
```

##### Dummy data

Looks like this:

```
# dummy data --------------------------------------------------------------
> df
        Meal_Number Meal_Type Class
44               52    Dinner     2
44.1             52    Dinner     2
44.2             52    Dinner     1
44.3             52    Dinner     1
44.4             52    Dinner     1
44.5             52    Dinner     1
44.6             52    Dinner     3
44.7             52    Dinner     3
44.8             52    Dinner     3
44.9             52    Dinner     3
44.10            52    Dinner     3
441              52     Lunch     2
44.11            52     Lunch     2
44.21            52     Lunch     1
44.31            52     Lunch     1
44.41            52     Lunch     1
44.51            52     Lunch     1
44.61            52     Lunch     3
44.71            52     Lunch     3
44.81            52     Lunch     3
44.91            52     Lunch     3
44.101           52     Lunch     3
442              53    Dinner     2
44.12            53    Dinner     2
44.22            53    Dinner     1
44.32            53    Dinner     1
44.42            53    Dinner     1
44.52            53    Dinner     1
44.62            53    Dinner     3
44.72            53    Dinner     3
44.82            53    Dinner     3
44.92            53    Dinner     3
44.102           53    Dinner     3
4411             53     Lunch     2
44.111           53     Lunch     2
44.211           53     Lunch     1
44.311           53     Lunch     1
44.411           53     Lunch     1
44.511           53     Lunch     1
44.611           53     Lunch     3
44.711           53     Lunch     3
44.811           53     Lunch     3
44.911           53     Lunch     3
44.1011          53     Lunch     3
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to split the data. You can use `table` or `ftable` directly on your whole dataset.

eg

```
data.frame(prop.table(table(df), 1))
```

Play with the `MARGIN` argument in the `prop.table` to see which one gives you the correct results. Also note that you can easily arrange/order the resulting dataframe to match your expected output